# How to generalize a list with different EntityField values

Tags: haskell, yesod, persistent

I try to generalize the URL handling when going to for example `/api/v1.0/events?order=-id,title` for a RESTful output - so the results will order by `id` desc, and than by `title` asc

Models file:

```
-- models

Event
    title Text
    content Text
    userId UserId
    deriving Eq
    deriving Show
```

Haskell file:

```
-- Events.hs

text2Order :: Text -> [SelectOpt Event]
text2Order text =
  case lookup textWithNoPrefix keyVal of
    Just val -> [direction val]
    Nothing -> error "wrong order"

  where
    keyVal = [ ("title", EventTitle)
             , ("user" , EventUserId)
             , ("id"   , EventId)
             ]

    textWithNoPrefix = if T.isPrefixOf "-" text
              then T.tail text
              else text

    direction = if T.isPrefixOf "-" text
              then Desc
              else Asc
```

I seem to have two problems:

1. Compiler doesn't like `keyVal` as its a list of tuple, where the 2nd value is different
2. Even though I assign `Asc` or `Desc` to `direction` the complier doesn't accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `EventTitle` and `EventUserId` are of *different* types, so you can't put the two of them in the same list. You can, however, put `EventTitle` and `EventContent` in the same list -- they both have type `EntityField Event Text`.

However, an approach like the following should work (using the Person example from the Yesod tutorial):

```
makeSelectOpt :: (Char,Char) -> SelectOpt Person
makeSelectOpt ('f','+') = Asc  PersonFirstName
makeSelectOpt ('f','-') = Desc PersonFirstName
makeSelectOpt ('l','+') = Asc  PersonLastName
makeSelectOpt ('l','-') = Desc PersonFirstName
makeSelectOpt ('a','+') = Asc  PersonAge
makeSelectOpt ('a','-') = Desc PersonAge

makeSelections :: [(Char,Char)] -> [SelectOpt Person]
makeSelections = map makeSelectOpt
```

You can factor out the +/- processing like this:

```
updown '+' = Asc
updown _   = Desc

makeSelectOpt' :: (Char,Char) -> SelectOpt Person
makeSelectOpt' ('f',dir)  = updown dir $ PersonFirstName
makeSelectOpt' ('l',dir)  = updown dir $ PersonLastName
makeSelectOpt' ('a',dir)  = updown dir $ PersonAge
```

If you want to perform error processing, return a `Maybe (SelectOpt Person)`:

```
makeSelectOpt'' :: (Char,Char) -> Maybe (SelectOpt Person)
makeSelectOpt'' ('f',dir)  = Just $ updown dir $ PersonFirstName
makeSelectOpt'' ('l',dir)  = Just $ updown dir $ PersonLastName
makeSelectOpt'' ('a',dir)  = Just $ updown dir $ PersonAge
makeSelectOpt'' _          = Nothing
```

and then:

```
makeSelectOpts'' :: [(Char,Char)] -> Maybe [SelectOpt Person)
makeSelectOpts'' pairs = mapM makeSelectOpt'' pairs
```

The result will be `Just [...]` if all of the pairs are valid and `Nothing` if any one of them isn't recognized.

**Update**

Here is another approach using existential types which looks a lot more like your code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

type ApplyToField = (forall t. EntityField Person t -> SelectOpt Person) -> SelectOpt Person

applyToFirstName, applyToLastName, applyToAge :: ApplyToField
applyToFirstName d = d PersonFirstName
applyToLastName d  = d PersonFirstName
applyToAge     d   = d PersonAge

makeSelectOpt''' :: (Char,Char) -> SelectOpt Person
makeSelectOpt''' (fld,d) = fn (updown d)
  where
    table = [ ('f',applyToFirstName), ('l',applyToLastName), ('a',applyToAge) ]
    fn = case lookup fld table of
           Just f -> f
           Nothing -> error "bad field spec"
```

Comment: Thanks. factoring out the direction is a bit harder, because we can have `id` and `-id` (i.e. no `+id`).

Comment: Not really - just return a Maybe (SelectOpt Person). I'll update my answer.

Comment: Well - I'm not going to update my answer - I've already written enough. If you find any of it useful perhaps you might up-vote it? The main point of the process is that you take the web parameters which you normalize into a canonical form - e.g. a list of pairs of Chars, for instance. Then you use what I've shown to translate the pairs to a list of SelectOpt Person. If something doesn't make sense or you need to ignore it, do that in the normalization step. The normalization step will only deal with strings so you won't run into any tricky type problems.