# Assigning Asc/ Desc to variable later causes a compiler error

Tags: haskell, yesod

I am getting a compiler error when I try to have something like:

```
getOrder :: Text -> SelectOpt Event
getOrder text =
    case text of
        "id"    -> direction EventId
        "title" -> direction EventTitle

    where direction = if text == "id" then Desc else Asc
```

If I change this line, it will work:

```
where direction = Asc
```

Same if I change the `case` - it will work:

```
case text of
    "id"    -> Desc EventId
    "title" -> Asc EventTitle
```

So my question is why assigning `Asc` and `Desc` cause the compiler error?

Comment: what is the error? My best guess: it's not defaulting to a generic function

Comment: btw: where is the point - the last snippet seems better anyway (why switch on `text` again?)

Comment: It is just a simplified version of the real case I have. My concern is why having the values in a variable cause it not to compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `direction` a function and move it to the top-level:

```
direction text = if text == "id" then Desc else Asc
```

See the `updown` function in this SO answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37380039/866915

**Update**

In order for `direction EventId` to make sense, `direction` has to have type:

```
direction :: EntityField Event Int
```

In order for `direction EventTitle` to make sense it has to have type:

```
direction :: EntityField Event String
```

So if `direction` is defined in a where clause like this

```
where direction = if ... then Asc else Desc
```

it can't satisfy both type constraints. However, if you make it a function:

```
direction t = if t == "id" then Asc else Desc
```

then it is polymorphic. That means that `direction ...` can have different types at different call sites.

**Update**

To use the original code, try adding the type signature:

```
where
  direction :: EntityField r t -> SelectOpt r
  direction = if text == "id" then Desc else Asc
```

Comment: But what is the reason moving it to top level will solve the errors?

Comment: It's a type error. I'll provide the exact one once in front of the computer :)

Comment: Your edit indeed makes sense. Is there a way to set the type of direction so it would become polymorphic?

Comment: Thanks @ErikR. Thanks to your suggestion, it seems that in fact just by letting direction get an argument (e.g. `direction t = ...`) solved the problem.